# How do you use a button as an input in python

Tags: python, button, time

I need to create a program that calculates a car's speed over a known distance (100m). I need the program to begin timing when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this is supposed to simulate when the car enters the monitored road section), stop timing when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, then calculate the car's average speed.

Comment: You mean real world car tracking? You should look for image processing

Comment: SO isn't a code creation service, you need to do the bulk of the work yourself. I will recommend you look at the modules `time`, for timing, and `tkinter` for the button/GUI. Read up on those and if you have problems with a program you've tried to make yourself, then ask.

Comment: Be more precise about the problem. Do you know how to take user inputs? How to get the time? How to calculate a speed given distance and time?

Comment: I've provided you a basic possible solution to measure time. As I said a possible solution (not the only one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> begin timing when the user presses Enter (this is supposed to simulate when the car enters the monitored road section), stop timing when the user presses Enter again, then calculate the car's average speed.

CLI version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import monotonic as timer

input("Press Enter to start timer") # wait for the first Enter from the user
start = timer()
input("Press Enter to stop timer")
elapsed = timer() - start
print("Speed {speed:f} m/s".format(speed=100 / elapsed))
```

To create a GUI stopwatch, you could use `tkinter`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import monotonic as timer
from tkinter import font, Tk, ttk

distance = 100 # meters
START, STOP = 'start', 'stop'

class Stopwatch(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        # create a button, run `.toggle_button` if it is pressed
        self.button = ttk.Button(parent,text=START, command=self.toggle_button)
        self.button.grid(sticky='nwse') # lays out the button inside the parent

    def toggle_button(self, event=None):
        if self.button is None: # close parent window
            self.parent.destroy()
        elif self.button['text'] == START: # start timer
            self.start = timer()
            self.button['text'] = STOP
        elif self.button['text'] == STOP: # stop timer, show result
            elapsed = timer() - self.start
            self.button.destroy()
            self.button = None
            text = "Speed {:.2f} m/s".format(distance / elapsed)
            ttk.Label(self.parent, text=text, anchor='center').grid()

root = Tk() # create root window
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)  # handle root window deletion
root.bind('<Return>', Stopwatch(root).toggle_button) # handle <Enter> key
root.mainloop()
```

You can both press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and click the button to call `.toggle_button()` method.

To make the main window larger, add after `root = Tk()` line:

```
root.title('Stopwatch') # set window title
root.geometry('400x300') # set window size
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # children widgets may fill the whole space
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').configure(size=25) # change default font size
```